# Loop a function in r to create a new table

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, substitution

I have a dataframe in r and want to perform the levene's/ variance test on multiple variables with two groups and save all results in a table. I have tried to do this using a for() loop and sapply() but I get neither working:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
  y = rnorm(100, 50, 1),
  z = rnorm(100, 70, 2),
  group = rep(c(0,1), each = 50)
)

varlist <- c("x","y","z")
res.var <- character(length(varlist))
res.f <- numeric(length(varlist))
res.p <- numeric(length(varlist))
```

Option 1)

```
for(i in seq_along(varlist)) {
  form <- substitute(i ~ group, list(i = as.name(varlist)))
  result <- var.test(
    formula = form,
    data = df)
  res.var[i] <- varlist[i]
  res.f[i] <- result$estimate
  res.p[i] <- result$p.value
}
```

Option 2:

```
sapply(varlist, function(x) {
  form <- substitute(i ~ group, list(i = as.name(varlist)))
  result <- var.test(
    formula = form,
    data = df)
  res.var[i] <- varlist[i]
  res.f[i] <- result$estimate
  res.p[i] <- result$p.value  
})
```

Maybe there's an easier way to that this. I'd be glad for any help ;o) Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `form  <- reformulate("group", varlist[i])` instead. The thing you are creating with the `substitute()` call is not a formula, it's an unevaulated expression. You need a proper formula. Although `group` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere so i'm not sure what is meant to be the desired output.

Comment: That doesn't work. "group" should stay the same because this variable determines the two variances that should be compared in var.test(). Basically, the loop should do "x ~ group", in the next iteration "y ~ group" and in the last iteration "z ~ group"

Comment: Well, i'm not sure exactly what doens't work. Are you getting an error? The example data you provided doesn't included `group` at all so it doesn't seem to be possible to actually test the code. But my code suggestion will return the formula you describe.

Comment: Ah the for() loop works now, although I don't really get why ;o) Thank you very much. However, the sapply function does not. I edited the original post and added simulated data. I hope that illustrates my problem.

Comment: In the `sapply` version you are using the variable `i` but that's not defined anywhere. That's the variable you used for the index in your for loop. Plus, since `sapply` uses a proper function, variable modified within the function are not changed in the global scope. Such a design does not work well with `sapply`. The `for` loop would likely be more efficient in this case since you've preallocated your output vectors.